# (Updated) Working with files, check if exists or not

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

I am working with files on C# and I got to a point where I don't know how to continue anymore.
The scenario is this: If I upload 3 or more files with the same name at the same time, I want to handle them and change their name to  from "myfile.pdf" to "myfile.pdf(1)/(2)/(3)..." depending on how much  files I upload.

This is what I have tried so far and in this case, this only works for only the second file because when the third one comes, it will check there is any file with the same - yes, okay name it "myfile.pdf(2) - but this exists too so it will go to another place.

How can I achieve having the same three files in the same folder with this naming convention?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
string FileName = "MyFile.pdf";
string path = @"C:\Project\MyPdfFiles\"

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                int i = 1;
                var FileExists = false;
                while (FileExists==false)
                {
                    if (FileExists == false)
                    {
                      FileName = FileName + "(" + i + ")";
                    }
                    else
                        return;
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

And the result of this code is: "MyFile.pdf", "MyFile.pdf(1)" And the third one doesn't load here.
I think I'm missing something in the loop or idk :(.
Can someone help me?

I have tried also this:

if(File.Exists(path) || File.Exists(path+"(")
//because when the second file its uploaded, its name will be SecondFile.pdf(1), so this will return true and will proceed running, but still the iteration will "always" start from 0 since everytime I upload a file, I have to refresh the process.

Comment: You never test your new path for existence

Comment: maybe rethink the folder estructure.. so you create a new folder on each request?

Comment: @CaiusJard , you're right, it should have been filename, I made a typo there.

Comment: @RuiCaramalho, that would bring us to the same scenario again. Then the folders would be with the same name, right? C:/File1/myfile.pdf , C:/File2/myfile.pdf

Comment: Are you coding the server, writing received files or are you coding a client, renaming files before upload?

Comment: @wmw147, maybe you could make sure the folder add an unique name.. using GUID or DateTime with milisecods in the folder name? or use this strategy on giving the name for the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating new folders with special names using the code below:

```
DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(FileDirectory);

            FileSystemInfo[] filesAndDirs = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFileSystemInfos("*" + FullFileName + "*");
            int i = filesAndDirs.Length;

            if (i>1)
            {
            FileName = Filename + "(" + i ")";
    }
```

So what this does is that it will count how many files we have in that folder with the same name, so I have to check if we have more than 1 file, then change it's name  to file(1).

Thank you to everyone that tried to help me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
public class Program
{

    public static string GetUnusedFilePath(string directorypath, string filename, string ext)
    {
        string fullPath = $"{directorypath}{filename}{ext}";
        int inc = 0;

        // check until you have a filepath that doesn't exist
        while (File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            fullPath = $"{directorypath}{filename}{inc}{ext}";
            inc++;
        }

        return fullPath;
    }

    public static void UploadFile(string filepath)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filepath))
        {
            // Add some text to file    
            Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("New Text File");
            fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] filestoUpload = { "file", "file", "file", "anotherfile", "anotherfile", "anotherfile" };
        string directorypath = @"D:\temp\";
        string ext = ".txt";

        foreach(var file in filestoUpload)
        {
            var filePath = GetUnusedFilePath(directorypath, file, ext);
            UploadFile(filePath);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: **FileName**.Exists is a typo

Comment: Please check the updated version of this question. I tried something else but still the iteration makes it a big problem since I have to refresh the whole program whenever I load a new file, so It will always start from 0...

Comment: @wmw147 strive to avoid editing questions in such a way that existing answers are invalidated. post anew

Comment: @wmw147 As you said there would be around 60000 files to upload. In general, how many duplicate entries would you get? 
If there are a lot, you can have a Dictionary<string, int> where the key string would be the duplicate filename. And the value int would be the available increment for upload.
If there isn't a lot you can try to fetch a valid path and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use return inside your while loop, better set 'FileExists = true' whenever you want you loop to stop. A return statement will exit your current method.

I think your problem can be easily solved using recursion, something like this (untested):

```
public class Program
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    
    public Program() {
        string fileName = "MyFile.pdf";
        string path = @"C:\Project\MyPdfFiles\";
        FileName = CheckFileName(path, fileName);
    }
    
    public string CheckFileName(string path, string fileName, int iteration = 0) {
        if (File.Exists($"{path}{fileName}")) {
            iteration++;
            CheckFileName(path, $"{fileName}({iteration})", iteration);
        }
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

What this does is: it `CheckFileName` method will keep calling itself until it finds a name that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Seems more logical than mine but I guess I forgot to mention that the program "refreshes" every time a new file is loaded, so the Iteration will "always" start from 0. So again, I will only get FileName.pdf and FileName.Pdf(1) but not the others.

Comment: Can you please check the updated version of this question?

Comment: So you get a list of files to upload and you want to check the filename when uploading them? Is it possible to share a bit more code?

Comment: I got more than 60.000 files to upload, but some of them are with the same name. What I want to do is for these files that have the same name, to change it to "name( i )" but looks like this is kind of impossible.

Comment: It's still unclear to me how you want to upload those files. One by one? Or do you have a list of files that need to be uploaded? If it is a list, are you uploading them async or not?